# how to decorate action in web api with ValidateInput(false)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

I am in need of migrating from normal `MVC` controller to `WebApi` controller.

My normal mvc controller.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Validate(string data)
{

}
```

WebApi Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)] 
// the moment I resolve the namespace System.Web.Mvc all the [HttpPost],[HttpGet] starts throwing error.
public HttpStatusCode Post([FromBody]string data)
{

}
```

Can somebody explain why so & how to address this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

To have an Api Controller, you'll have to inherit from `ApiController`. Also, if by adding the Namespace you start getting errors, then you will have to add the namespace explicitly to the attributes like this for example. `System.Web.Http.HttpPost`.

Answer (score 0):

You **don't really have to use something like [ValidateInput(false)]** in your web api, it's meant to prevent XSS attacks in MVC applications.

Also, the namespace you have to refer is **System.Web.Http**.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 0):

I used htmlEncode in javascript from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219983) and HttpUtility.HtmlDecode in C#